# Nodejs issue with writing request url, response to file synchronously after get api request

Tags: javascript, node.js

I searched a lot on StackOverflow posts and able to figure out my program up to this level, however, I am unable to proceed forward. Need your suggestions on this if you can advise.

I am running a get API by taking in 2 request URLs one after the other using a URL array and using for loop to process each URL and send it to request.get and able to see the responses in the console.

However, the issue is with when I try to write the request URL and its corresponding response to file using the test case names serially from test case name array.

It's only writing the file with TC2_reqres.json and putting the request response of the first call.

Expecting something like this

TC1_reqres.json contains  /people/1 response
TC2_reqres.json contains /people/2 response

Please suggest.

Thanks! much to all of ya in advance.

```
var request = require("request");
var fs = require('fs');

describe('testsuite', function () {
  it("test case", function (done) {
    var urlarr = ["https://swapi.co/api/people/1", "https://swapi.co/api/people/2"];
    var tcnamearr = ["TC1", "TC2"];
    var respath = "C:/Study_JSR/capi/tests/Res/";
    for (var i = 0; i < tcnamearr.length; i++) {
      url = urlarr[i];
      tcname = tcnamearr[i];
      request.get({ url: url, "rejectUnauthorized": false, "json": true }, function (e, r, user) {
        resbod = JSON.stringify(user);
        console.log("resbod: " + resbod);
        fs.writeFileSync(respath + tcname + "_reqres.json", resbod);
      })
    }
    done();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try instead of `var` to use `let`

`for (let i = 0; i < tcnamearr.length; i++) {`

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has strange behaviour with closures and async calls. The `for` loop completes before the callbacks are called so the value of `tcname` is always "TC2".
You should try to refactor the code.
Use `axios` instead of `request`. It support promises and it's better in these scenarios.

One possible solution is this:

```
var request = require("axios");
var fs = require('fs');

describe('testsuite', function () {
  it("test case", function (done) {

    var respath = "C:/Study_JSR/capi/tests/Res/";

    var gets = [
      request.get({ url: "https://swapi.co/api/people/1", "rejectUnauthorized": false, "json": true }),
      request.get({ url: "https://swapi.co/api/people/2", "rejectUnauthorized": false, "json": true })
    ]

    Promise.all(gets).then(function(res) {
      fs.writeFileSync(respath + "TC1" + "_reqres.json", res[0].body)
      fs.writeFileSync(respath + "TC2" + "_reqres.json", res[1].body)
    })

    done();
  });
});
```

It's just a starting point, you can remove duplications if you need.